# change image when comma and dot are availble

Tags: javascript

i have this code if i type text to the textbox and click speek their speech someone talking but if their comma or dot the speech always stop for mill seconds, i want to call silentGIF if no speek and if the speech talking to display lipGIF idea is the gif and speek  to be like someone talking, but LipGIF is always displaying and silent Gif not displaying please help

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea id="textToSpeak" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text to speak..."></textarea>
    <button id="speakButton">Speak</button>
</div>
<img id="lipGif" src="image/dux1.gif" alt="Lips animation">
<img id="lipSilent" src="image/duxsilent.gif" alt="silent animation">

<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const textToSpeakInput = document.getElementById('textToSpeak');
            const speakButton = document.getElementById('speakButton');
            const lipGif = document.getElementById('lipGif');
            const lipSilent = document.getElementById('lipSilent');

            speakButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const text = textToSpeakInput.value.trim();
                if (text !== '') {
                    speakText(text);
                    showLipAnimation();
                } else {
                    alert('Please enter some text to speak.');
                }
            });

            function speakText(text) {
                // Insert a pause after each '.' or ','
                text = text.replace(/([.,])/g, '$1<break time="200ms"/>');

                const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
                utterance.onstart = function() {
                    showLipAnimation();
                };
                utterance.onend = function() {
                    hideLipAnimation();
                };
                speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

                // Set up an interval that checks the 'speaking' property every 100 milliseconds
                const checkSpeaking = setInterval(function() {
                    if (speechSynthesis.speaking) {
                        showLipAnimation();
                    } else {
                        showSilentAnimation();
                    }
                }, 100);

                // Clear the interval when the speech ends
                utterance.onend = function() {
                    clearInterval(checkSpeaking);
                    hideLipAnimation();
                };
            }

            function showLipAnimation() {
                lipGif.style.display = 'inline';
                lipSilent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function hideLipAnimation() {
                lipGif.style.display = 'none';
                lipSilent.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function showSilentAnimation() {
                lipGif.style.display = 'none';
                lipSilent.style.display = 'inline';
            }
        });
    </script>
```